# Kubernetes Ingress not forwarding routes

Tags: kubernetes, dns, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am fairly new to `Kubernetes` and have just deployed my first cluster to `IBM Cloud`. When I created the cluster, I get a dedicated ingress subdomain, which I will be referring to as `<long-k8subdomain>.cloud` for the scope of this post. Now, this subdomain works for my app. For example: `<long-k8subdomain>.cloud/ping` works from my browser/curl just fine- I get the expected JSON response back. But, if I add this subdomain to a CNAME record on my domain provider's DNS settings (I have used `Bluehost` and `IBM Cloud's Internet Services`), I get a `404` response back from all routes. However this response is the default `nginx` 404 response (it says "nginx" under "404 Not Found"). I believe this means that this means the ingress load balancer is being reached, but the request does not get routed right. I am using `Kubernetes version 1.20.12_1561 on VPC gen 2` and this is my ingress-config.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "public-iks-k8s-nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "Host: <long-k8subdomain>.cloud";
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <long-k8subdomain>.cloud
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service-name
            port:
              number: 80
```

I am pretty sure this problem is due to the annotations. Maybe I am using the wrong ones or I do not have enough. Ideally, I would like something like this: api..com/ to route correctly. I have also read a little bit about default backends, but I have not dove too much into that just yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have spent multiple hours trying to fix this.

Some sources I have used:

- https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-cs_network_planning
- https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-ingress-types
- https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-comm-ingress-annotations#annotations

**Note**: The reason why I have the second annotation is because for some reason, requests without that header were not being routed directly. So that was part of my debugging process and I just ended up leaving it as I am not sure if that annotation solves that, so I left it for now.

Comment: You can look at this article: [How to Use the Ingress Application Load Balancer to Expose an App Outside a Kubernetes Cluster](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/how-to-use-the-ingress-application-load-balancer-to-expose-an-app-outside-a-kubernetes-cluster)

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the response however my app is hosted inside the Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the NGINX ingress controller to route requests for your own domain's CNAME record to the service instead of the IBM Cloud one, you need a rule in the ingress where the `host` identifies your domain.

For instance, if your domain's DNS entry is `api.example.com`, then change the resource YAML to:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "public-iks-k8s-nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: api.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service-name
            port:
              number: 80
```

You should not need the second annotation for this to work.

If you want both of the hosts to work, then you could add a second rule instead of replacing host in the existing one.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much. Everything is working now